# Are there any episodes of Digimon that weren't dubbed to English?

Tags: digimon

During Season 2 there's a scene where Izie (I think) is explaining how the last Digidestined gave up their crests to restore the world. However, I don't ever remember seeing that. The only time I remember seeing them lose their crests was when the Tags and Crests were destroyed in the last episode of the first season, and they realize that the real Crests had always been inside them.

I'm wondering if there was an OVA or something that takes place between the first and second seasons where the digital world is brought to ruin and the Digidestined have to give up their crests to restore it.

Comment: You mean dubbed into English, right?

Comment: @JNat yeh, i'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no OVA, all you get is a narrated flashback.

In season 2 ep 27 Izzy tells the new Digidestined about how the original eight went to the Digital World and spoke with Jeni. Jeni instructed them to, "release the powers that protect the Digital World". This meant releasing the powers of the crests, from within themselves, in order the defeat the darkness and spread, "a coating of goodness" over the world. This brought peace and beauty to the Digital World.

Even though the crests were destroyed, the power of the crests still remained inside of the Digidestined. It was that power that was released.